# Is there a way to print out single values from a multidimentional list? in python please

Tags: multidimensional-array

Imagine i have a multidimensional List like this vals = [['John', '20'], ['Derron', '5'], ['Mike', '43']], what can i do to print out only the names e.g: John, Derron, Mike

Answer (score 0):

In which language you want to do this? Using JavaScript you can try below solution.

```
function print(val) {
    console.log(val[0]) 
}

vals.forEach(print)
```

Comment: i need to do this in python please

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for loop. In python For example:

```
for sublist in vals:
   print(sublist[0])
```

The first line of this code will loop through each sublist. For this question, ['John','20'] is a sublist. The second line will print out the first element (aka name) of each of these sublists.